# How to render HTML predefined tag in Razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to render the HTML predefined tag (between h2 to h6) based on what is set in my model. Below is the snippet. I am facing issue in my closing tag. closing tag is not processed and it is considered as text and it is truncated in the page view source.

```
string subArticleLevel = "h2";
if(subarticle.SubTitleLevel!=null)
{
   subArticleLevel = subarticle.SubTitleLevel;
}                
<@subArticleLevel>@subarticle.SubTitle</@subArticleLevel>
```

Comment: `<@subArticleLevel>@subarticle.SubTitle</@subArticleLevel>` renders correct `h2` for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Html.Raw` method with explicit code block notation.

```
@Html.Raw("<")@(subArticleLevel)@Html.Raw(">")@(subarticle.SubTitle) 
                                        @Html.Raw("</")@(subArticleLevel)@Html.Raw(">")
```

**Or**

Simply use `@:` prefix to denote it is a start of an html block, if you are already in a code block. The below should work fine.

```
@{
    string subArticleLevel = "h2";
    string subarticleSubTitle = "test";
    @:<@subArticleLevel>@subarticleSubTitle</@subArticleLevel>
}
```

Comment: when i use your 2nd method, am getting rendered source as  <subarticlelevel>test</subarticlelevel>. But expecting as  <h2>test</h2>

Comment: are you sure ? Because it works for me. Here is a working dotnetfiddle you can check https://dotnetfiddle.net/HIEvXN

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of MVC you are on but if you have c# 6 you might just use c# string interpolation.

```
 @($"<{subArticleLevel}>{subarticle.SubTitle}</{subArticleLevel}>")
```

I haven't tried it but if you are getting html encoding you could try.

```
@Html.Raw($"<{subArticleLevel}>{subarticle.SubTitle}</{subArticleLevel}>")
```

If you don't have c# 6 available you can try .

```
@Html.Raw(string.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", subArticleLevel, subarticle.SubTitle))
```